# create random number from a poisson dist. using MersenneTwister

Tags: c++, poisson

Hi I have a simulation I'm runnning in which I get random numbers from a uniform and normal distributions easily:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MersenneTwister.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    MTRand mtrand1;
    double r1,r2;
    r1 = mtrand.rand(); // from a uninform dist.
    r2 = mtrand1.randNorm(); //from a normal dist.
}
```

I would like to use this random number generator to obtain a random number from a poisson distribution with mean 'A'.

Any idea about how to implement this procedure using the MersseneTwister code?
the code can be found here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=11960. and it is widely used.

Comment: You do know these are all in `random`?

Comment: If you mean the use of the package <random>, there is no need to use it. If not please clarify your comment.

Comment: What do you mean there is "no need"? The functionality is already there. And yes, I do mean the standard library

Comment: Ok, so if u can provide a solution please do so

Comment: Um.... but what's your problem statement? Do you want a poisson distribution you want to use? Do you want the sampling algorithm to form a poisson distribution? Must you use the included header in your question? What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard library

```
#include<random>

double mean = 3.1415926;
std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
std::poisson_distribution<> pd{mean};

auto n = pd(mt);  // get a number
```

Do note that seeding with `std::random_device` is [unlikely to be satisfactory](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/ease-of-use-without-loss-of-power.html).